# vhost nginx: No input file specified

Tags: nginx, silex

I'm trying to build a web page using Silex and Nginx, but I might have something wrong in the server definition because when I try to access it the following error appears:

```
No input file specified.
```

My server definition is the following:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name comparer.com;
    root /var/www/comparer.com/web/public;
    index index.php;

    #site root is redirected to the app boot script
    location = / {
        try_files @site @site;
    }

    #all other locations try other files first and go to our front controller if none of them exists
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @site;
    }

    #return 404 for all php files as we do have a front controller
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    location @site {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have trying different configurations but any worked.

To be more secure, I want to have my index.php in the public folder, but I don't know if Silex permit me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration looks OK. Do you have index.php in the /var/www/comparer.com/web/public now?

As for Silex conventions, they says nothing about public folder, try `root /var/www/comparer.com/web` also.

[Webserver Configuration - Documentation - Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html)

Comment: Thanks Aleksey, after a while I discovered that I had another config file, so I was editing the wrong config.